# Gvim File Extension specific tablength

Tags: file, tabstop, vim

Is it possible in Gvim to set tablength according to the name extension of the file which is being edited ?

```
set tabstop=8  // For *.cpp
set tabstop=3  // For *.svh
set tabstop=8  // For *.pl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your vimrc:

```
 autocmd FileType cpp set tabstop=8
 autocmd FileType svh set tabstop=3
 autocmd FileType pl set tabstop=8
```

Habi